# node js pass paramater to mongoose model

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I would like to pass a parameter from my route to my model.
This is what I have in routes/data.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Data = require('../models/data')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  Data("object").find().where('dos').ne([])
  .exec((err, data) => {
    res.send(data);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

model/data.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Data = (doc) => mongoose.model(doc,new mongoose.Schema({}), doc);

exports.Data = Data;
```

The code compliles but when I run it I got this error:
`(node:25344) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Data is not a function at C:\Users\project\routes\data.js:7:3`

Comment: try importing like this `const { Data } = require('../models/data')`

Comment: So simple but it worked.

Comment: adding it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing this:

`const { Data } = require('../models/data')`

because you have exported the function as `exports.Data = Data;`
not like `module.exports = Data`, so this wont work as `const Data = require('../models/data')`.